# Activities in Warsaw during a public holiday

Tags: poland, public-holidays, warsaw

I'm planning on visiting Warsaw, including a public holiday (Corpus Christi). I am planning on a morning mass in the old city and possibly joining the procession after that.

What leisure activities are available?

As far as I can tell, all museums are closed this day.  My reading of the visiting hours at [Royal Łazienki park](https://www.lazienki-krolewskie.pl/en/zwiedzanie/godziny-otwarcia) is that the palaces will be closed, but the gardens will be accessible (and free of charge, because it's Thursday), so I'm guessing many locals will enjoy a picnic on that day.  Is that correct, and what else is popular?

Comment: It's way to broad, but about Łazienki, the garden is opened until dawn, it's free of charge, and by good weather there are a lot of people. However, picknicking is forbidden.